# cannot install vim-plug on windows

Tags: neovim

I was trying to install plug-ins for neovim. Hence, I tried to install vim-plug from [here](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#windows-powershell-1)

While I ran it on powershell, it was unable to connect to the server.

```
iwr : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ iwr -useb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem.

```
iwr : Unable to connect to the remote server
```

you can download plug.vim manually and put it in the "autoload" directory.
no need to use that script.